# Background Color is not showing with dynamically added Tailwind classes Via Handlebar Helper on iPhone Chrome

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, tailwind-css, handlebars.js

I am having an issue with Google Chrome and Safari browsers on my iPhone.
The issue:
I am using Tailwind CSS with React and Handlebar templates and using a custom Handlebar Helper function.
I have dynamically generated Tailwind classes to change the Background Colour of a TR element at runtime using a Handlebar Helper function.
The code is working fine with Desktop and Android devices- the correct tailwind classes are generated and Inspect Element on the desktop shows that the CSS is loaded correctly, however, Google Chrome and Safari on iPhone are not showing the background colour.
When I hardcode the class names in the Handlebar template instead of dynamically generated class names, the background colour works just fine in all the browsers (both desktop/android and iPhone). However, when the class names are dynamically generated via HanldeBar Helper, iPhone browsers stall.
I am attaching the screenshots from different browsers: Please help.

React Component:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, useRef} from 'react';
import Handlebars from 'handlebars';
import moment from 'moment-timezone';
import parse from "html-react-parser";

const MyComponent = ({data}) => {
  
  const [html, setHtml] = useState ("");

  const generateHandlebarHtml = () =>
  {
    const template = `
    <div> 
    <div>Prayer Time</div>
    <div class="prayer-time-container">
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="300px" align="center">
        <tr>
          <td  class="px-4 py-4 border-b border-slate-200" style="width: 10%">&nbsp;</td>
          <td  class="py-4 border-b border-slate-200" style="width: 30%;">Prayer</td>
          <td  class="py-4 border-b border-slate-200" style="width: 30%">Begins</td>
          <td  class="py-4 border-b border-slate-200" style="width: 30%">Iqamah</td>
        </tr>
        <tr {{highlight "12:00 AM" fajr_jamah}}>
          <td  class="px-4 py-4 border-b border-slate-200" style="width: 10%"><img src="/images/fajr.png" width="24px" style="min-width: 24px;" /></td>  
          <td  class="py-4 border-b border-slate-200" style="width: 30%">Fajr</td>
          <td  class="py-4 border-b border-slate-200" style="width: 30%">{{fajr_begins}}</td>
          <td  class="py-4 border-b border-slate-200" style="width: 30%">{{fajr_jamah}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr {{highlight fajr_jamah sunrise}}>
          <td  class="px-4 py-4 border-b border-slate-200" style="width: 10%"><img src="/images/sunrise.png" width="24px" style="min-width: 24px;" /></td>  
          <td  class="py-4 border-b border-slate-200" style="width: 30%;">Sunrise</td>
          <td  class="py-4 border-b border-slate-200" style="width: 60%;  text-align: center;" colspan="2">{{sunrise}}</td>
          
        </tr>
        <tr {{highlight sunrise zuhr_jamah}}>
          <td  class="px-4 py-4 border-b border-slate-200" style="width: 10%"><img src="/images/zuhr.png" width="24px" style="min-width: 24px;" /></td>  
          <td  class="py-4 border-b border-slate-200" style="width: 30%">Zuhr</td>
          <td  class="py-4 border-b border-slate-200" style="width: 30%">{{zuhr_begins}}</td>
          <td  class="py-4 border-b border-slate-200" style="width: 30%">{{zuhr_jamah}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr {{highlight zuhr_jamah asr_jamah}}>
          <td  class="px-4 py-4 border-b border-slate-200" style="width: 10%"><img src="/images/asr.png" width="24px" style="min-width: 24px;" /></td>  
          <td  class="py-4 border-b border-slate-200" style="width: 30%">Asr</td>
          <td  class="py-4 border-b border-slate-200" style="width: 30%">{{asr_mithl_2}}</td>
          <td  class="py-4 border-b border-slate-200" style="width: 30%">{{asr_jamah}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr {{highlight asr_jamah maghrib_jamah}}>
          <td  class="px-4 py-4 border-b border-slate-200" style="width: 10%"><img src="/images/magrib.png" width="24px" style="min-width: 24px;" /></td>  
          <td  class="py-4 border-b border-slate-200" style="width: 30%">Maghrib</td>
          <td  class="py-4 border-b border-slate-200" style="width: 30%">{{maghrib_begins}}</td>
          <td  class="py-4 border-b border-slate-200" style="width: 30%">{{maghrib_jamah}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr {{highlight maghrib_jamah isha_jamah}}>
          <td  class="px-4 py-4 border-b border-slate-200" style="width: 10%;"><img src="/images/isha.png" width="24px" style="min-width: 24px;" /></td>  
          <td  class="py-4 border-b border-slate-200" style="width: 30%">Isha</td>
          <td  class="py-4 border-b border-slate-200" style="width: 30%">{{isha_begins}}</td>
          <td  class="py-4 border-b border-slate-200" style="width: 30%">{{isha_jamah}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    </div>
  `;

  // Compile the template with Handlebars
   
  Handlebars.registerHelper({    
    highlight: (v1, v2) => {        
        var prevPrayerTime = moment().tz("Australia/Sydney").format('YYYY-MM-DD') + " " + v1;        
        var currPrayerTime = moment().tz("Australia/Sydney").format('YYYY-MM-DD') + " " + v2;        
        var currentTime = moment().tz("Australia/Sydney").format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm A');       
                
        var prevPrayerTimestamp = new Date(prevPrayerTime).getTime();
        var currPrayerTimestamp = new Date(currPrayerTime).getTime();
        var currentTimestamp = new Date(currentTime).getTime();
        
        return (currentTimestamp > prevPrayerTimestamp) && (currentTimestamp < currPrayerTimestamp) ? new Handlebars.SafeString('class="bg-yellow-300 scale-100"'): '';
    
    }
  });

  // Generate HTML with your data
  const compiledTemplate = Handlebars.compile(template);
      setHtml(compiledTemplate(data));
  }

  useEffect(async () => {
    generateHandlebarHtml();
  }, []);
  
  return (<div id="dynamic-html"><div>{parse(html)}</div></div>);
  
};

export default MyComponent;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi I have also tried putting the style tag directly instead of Tailwind classes but without any luck on iPhone Chrome (android and desktop chromes are working fine): 

return (currentTimestamp > prevPrayerTimestamp) && (currentTimestamp < currPrayerTimestamp) ? new Handlebars.SafeString('style="background-color: #FFFF00; transform: scale(1);"'): '';